# How to save instance for an image using iTextSharp to be saved as a PDF in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

IDE : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Platform : C#

I am trying to save the image in memory stream which needs to be shown in PDF using iTextSharp.text.Image object, in which I am getting an error which says, The byte array is not a recognized image format.

So, this is what I have tried so far:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, memoryStream);
    Doc.Open();

    chart1.SaveImage(memoryStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
    img.ScalePercent(75f);
    Doc.Add(img);
    Doc.Close();
    byte[] content = memoryStream.ToArray();
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create("D:\\Test2.pdf"))
    {
        fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\Test2.pdf");
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you save `memoryStream` to a file? Is it a valid PNG file? Because iText supports PNG, so it should recognize the image, unless the image is corrupt or not a real PNG.

Comment: See , I am using chart control and that control is saved in Png format before saving to PDF...

Comment: That's not an answer to my question.

Comment: I don't know , can you suggest me how to proceed as of now... Thanks

Comment: You are dealing with two proprietary abstractions, a "chart" and a "document" as well as two unrelated binary file specifications, PNG and PDF. You are trying to jam the realizations of these two abstractions into the same byte array (your `MemoryStream`). Generally speaking, combining two files in this manner almost never works. Instead, you need to save your chart to a file (could be in-memory, doesn't matter) but iText should not be involved in this process. Then, once you've got an image (and have verified it), you can just `Doc.Add()` it.